# Antlr 4 C# Error Listener

Tags: c#, antlr

How do you get the BaseErrorListener in the Antlr 4 c# target?  It does not appear to be there by default.  I am trying to redirect the error information from the console to an internal data structure for later use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full name of the class is `Antlr4.Runtime.BaseErrorListener`.